# SQL ordering first alphabetically and then via custom boolean column

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM champions WHERE Patch_No = '3.03' ORDER BY Champion ASC, New DESC
```

Here is how my table looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/23Uk0.png I'm trying first to get the alphabetical order and then move rows with New = 1 to the top my query only sorts alphabetically for some reason

Comment: maybe if you had a tie-breaker situation to show. Maybe what you have is great

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `New` to be at the top, it needs to b the *first* key, not the second:

```
ORDER BY `new` DESC, Champion ASC
```

Comment: that is the answer, I thought that New should be the second key since we sort after alphabetically again, I'll mark it as an anwer in 9 minutes.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You simply have your order by clause backwards :)

By putting it like this

```
SELECT * FROM champions WHERE Patch_No = '3.03' ORDER BY New DESC, Champion ASC
```

the query will order first by whether or not it is new, and then by the alphabetical champion name.

fiddler here
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b2610/1